# Indexing operations on a 8TB AX dynamics database

Tags: sql-server, index, microsoft-dynamics

We have an 8TB AX dynamics database on SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition.
Our team would like to perform indexing operations but for a max of 8 hours with minimal impact during the week. My recommendation was to run online operations using Ola's script during the week and allow offline during weekend only.

The feedback I got is that Ola's script creates a worktable (to do list of operations) at every invocation of the script, That is correct.

They rather have a script that creates a worktable initially and only creates a new worktable when the previous one is completely handled, to avoid some indexes that are never touched.

Is somebody aware of such a script?

Comment: By index maintenance I assume you mean reorganize and / or rebuild operations on rowstore indexes?...if so, why?

Comment: Which version of ax?

Comment: As you've heard, Ola's scripts are not going to scale well for your database size.  Most of the time will be dedicated to analyzing indexes rather than maintaining them.  You will likely need to build your own custom scripts that fit your business requirements.